# Unable to capture touchpad release event in React

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent

I'm working on a React application where I need to perform certain actions when the user releases their touchpad (trackpad) on macOS. I've tried using the mouseup event, but it doesn't seem to be triggered consistently on touchpad releases.

I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate event to handle touchpad releases, or if there's a specific consideration I need to take into account for touchpad interactions.

Here's a simplified version of my React component:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const handleTouchpadRelease = () => {
    // Code to be executed when the touchpad is released
    console.log('Touchpad released!');
  };

  return (
    <div onTouchEnd={handleTouchpadRelease}>
      {/* My component content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Despite using onTouchEnd, the function doesn't seem to be called consistently when releasing the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

You should try listening to `pointer*` events to work with ***[trackpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/pointerdown_event)***.

```js
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const handlePointerDown = () => {
    // Your code for trackpad withold
  };

  const handlePointerUp = () => {
    // Your code for trackpad release
  };

  return (
    <div onPointerDown={handlePointerDown}
      onPointerUp={handlePointerUp}
    >
      {/* My component content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-frog-l5hhfp?file=/src/App.js)**